# Android weight attribute

Tags: android

It's just freaking me out, but I can't make my layout depend on weight. There are two relative layouts and two linear layouts and some elements in both of these layouts. I've put `android:layout_weight="0.2` to the first one, `android:layout_weight="0.1` to the second one, `android:layout_weight="0.5` to the third one, and `android:layout_weight="0.2` to the last one. The sum is 1, right? But it doesn't work. I'm afraid, it's because of different layout_height and maybe different categories of layouts? The XML-code is [here](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1e44)

Comment: Why are you using layout_weight inside a scroll view. You are trying to divide the full screen based on weights. When you do that, there no posiblity for scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with the layout_weight attribute is the following:
Set all layout_height (or width depends on what you are doing) to fill_parent or wrap_content (it should be the same value for all elements). Try both versions. Sometimes wrap_content is better sometimes fill_parent is better.

There are many theories about the mystic of the layout_weight attribute.
This is my version^^

Edit: I forgot to mention, that the logic is inverted: the less weight the bigger the element.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced that setting the width or height (depending on which direction you want your layouts to span) to 0 can be usefull from time to time.

It is possible that you might need to use the value "0.4f", when you use values > 1.

You could also try setting the `weight_sum` to an amount (in your example it could be 10) and then use the `layout_weight` values 2, 1, 5 and 2 - but I'm not sure that it will make a difference.